# Macro to get document contents preserving hyphenation in libreoffice writer

Tags: python, macros, libreoffice

I need to access the text in a LibreOffice document.
The document has automatic hyphenation,
and I need to know the hyphen positions as they are displayed on screen.

The following code returns clear text without automatic hyphens:

```
XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getText().getString()
```

This is the documentation I read:
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Working_with_Text_Documents

Also I looked at this extension: https://github.com/voikko/libreoffice-voikko

I also ran the [Capitalise.py example](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_samples#Capitalize.py) under pyCharm remote debugger, but couldn't find any hints.

Comment: Could you ask a clear question and provide a specific example of input and output in addition to what you have already done.

Comment: It wasn't clear enough? I need to access text in libreoffice document and I need to know hyphen positions as they are displayed on screen. 
XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getText().getString() return clear text without automatic hyphens.

Comment: It is not and likely why you do not have much interest or any response.  Please review this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic hyphens do not actually occur in the text in LibreOffice.  Instead, they are displayed as needed.  When a format such as PDF is exported, or if the document is printed, then hyphens are shown in the output.

The [Hyphenator service](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/linguistic2/Hyphenator.html) is fairly easy to use in macros, and allows a word to be split up according to possible hyphenation positions.

To really determine where hyphens are getting displayed on screen, the following may work:

1. Traverse the document with a word cursor.  [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section 7.3.8.5 gives an example of this in Basic.
2. Move the view cursor to the beginning of each word and check the Y position.  For example, if `self.oVC` is the view cursor, then check the value of `self.oVC.getPosition().Y`.
3. Move the cursor to the end of the word, and see if the Y position changed.

If it did, then presumably the word was hyphenated.

Comment: Thank you. I did it similar way ( http://pastebin.com/h6wUmkqs ), but this gives me some nice ideas like getPosition() and using hyphenator service to check for hyphen. But still, this is looks rather an ugly hack which is sad